# Time-series table in React

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, time-series, plotly, timeserieschart

How can I create tables such as these in React?

[Superset time-series table picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUfzr.png)
[Superset time-series table picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKwiq.jpg)

I am open to using any packages, preferably commonly used ones such as plotly

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries to complete your task.

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/table

```
<TableContainer>
  <Table variant='simple'>
    <TableCaption>Imperial to metric conversion factors</TableCaption>
    <Thead>
      <Tr>
        <Th>To convert</Th>
        <Th>into</Th>
        <Th isNumeric>multiply by</Th>
      </Tr>
    </Thead>
    <Tbody>
      <Tr>
        <Td>inches</Td>
        <Td>millimetres (mm)</Td>
        <Td isNumeric>25.4</Td>
      </Tr>
      <Tr>
        <Td>feet</Td>
        <Td>centimetres (cm)</Td>
        <Td isNumeric>30.48</Td>
      </Tr>
      <Tr>
        <Td>yards</Td>
        <Td>metres (m)</Td>
        <Td isNumeric>0.91444</Td>
      </Tr>
    </Tbody>
    <Tfoot>
      <Tr>
        <Th>To convert</Th>
        <Th>into</Th>
        <Th isNumeric>multiply by</Th>
      </Tr>
    </Tfoot>
  </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

You can also create the line chart by d3.js or chart.js

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't d3.js and plotly charts have too many legends/auxiliary to be plugged into the table? In the image I posted, it is just a clean line